# what does _cb mean in function name clk_init_cb?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In linux 5.4.21 source code drivers/clk/clk.c, I see this structure definition.

```
struct clock_provider {
    void (*clk_init_cb)(struct device_node *);
    struct device_node *np;
    struct list_head node;
};
```

In member function name `clk_init_cb`, what does `_cb` mean?

Comment: Usually `cb` refers to Callback functions.

Comment: **C**all**B**ack. If you want more, in OOP (yes, kernel is heavily using OOP paradigm) this is the part of a constructor method, I.e. constructor of the inherited object.

Comment: thanks all for the comment.  if you write an anwer I'll select.